# codeigniter : how to avoid db query returns last statement as key value

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I execute several queries before querying a result in codeigniter:

```
$sql_drop_temptable = "...blabla...";
$sql_prepare = "it creates a temporary table; where I sum up later...";
$sql_summe = " select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(summands))) from workday;";

$query = $this->db->query($sql_drop_temptable);
$query = $this->db->query($sql_prepare);
$query = $this->db->query($sql_summe)->row();
var_dump($query);
```

How  can I avoid to get the last sql statement ($sql_summe) as the keyname in the result set ?
It is difficult for me get the result in a scalar.
The result looks like:

```
object(stdClass)[41]
   public 'sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(summands)))' => string '00:23:54' (length=8)
```

Usually I see column names as key-values. But on this one there is no column name due to the sum function, so it uses the sql statement as key value. (?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename it using `AS`in your query:

```
SELECT sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(summands))) AS something ...
```

And now `something` will be the key instead.